# Rails 3.1 scope ignored when joining twice to the same table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, scope

I am running into a problem when joining to the same table twice in separate scopes using rails 3.1.4.  One of the scopes is entirely ignored, including both the join and where clauses.  This removal happens without an error or notice.

This is a simplified example of what is causing the problem:

Task is a standard rails model with a polymorphic relationship to the model SavedOutput.  SavedOuput is used as a cache to store the results of complex methods.

The task model looks like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :saved_outputs
  scope :saved_lates, lambda { joins(:saved_outputs).where(
    "saved_outputs.method" => "late?",
    "saved_outputs.output" => true
  )}
  scope :saved_completes, lambda { joins(:saved_outputs).where(
    "saved_outputs.method" => "complete?",
    "saved_outputs.output" => true
  )}
  ...
```

With this code, I can call `Task.saved_lates` instead of calling something like `Task.all.select(&:late?)` assuming the cached data is current.

The problem is that calling `Task.saved_lates.saved_completes` does not work.  I believe rails' duplicate query detection kicks in and removes the second scope.  Even if that didn't happen, the query would still fail because you can't join to the same table twice without using an alias in MYSQL.

I have a partial solution with a manually written join and table alias.

```
  scope :saved_lates, lambda { joins("INNER JOIN saved_outputs AS so1 ON so1.object_type='Task' AND so1.object_id=tasks.id").where(
    "so1.method" => "late?",
    "so1.output" => true
  )}
  scope :saved_completes, lambda { joins(INNER JOIN saved_outputs AS so2 ON so2.object_type='Task' AND so2.object_id=tasks.id).where(
    "so2.method" => "complete?",
    "so2.output" => true
  )}
```

The problem with this solution is that the alias `so1` needs to be unique throughout the entire project.  Considering that the SavedOutput model saves the outputs of many different models, I would need to use a global unique id or unique hash system to label the aliases.

Is there a solution to the silent removal of a scope from a query?
Is there a way to force rails to create a unique table alias on every standard join?
Is it bad practice to use the joins scope with association symbols as arguments?

---

Here is a complete example of what I am looking at:

```
class ScopeTest < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t| 
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :active, :default => true
    end 

    create_table :bars do |t| 
      t.integer :foo_id
      t.boolean :method_value
    end 
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  scope :ones, lambda { joins(:bars).where("bars.method_value" => true) }
  scope :zeroes, lambda { joins(:bars).where("bars.method_value" => false) }
end
```

The results of running the scopes and chaining the scopes:

```
irb(main):022:0> Foo.ones.to_sql
=> "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` INNER JOIN `bars` ON `bars`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id` WHERE `bars`.`method_value` = 1"
irb(main):023:0> Foo.zeroes.to_sql
=> "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` INNER JOIN `bars` ON `bars`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id` WHERE `bars`.`method_value` = 0"
irb(main):024:0> Foo.ones.zeroes.to_sql
=> "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` INNER JOIN `bars` ON `bars`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id` WHERE `bars`.`method_value` = 0"
irb(main):025:0> Foo.zeroes.ones.to_sql
=> "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` INNER JOIN `bars` ON `bars`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id` WHERE `bars`.`method_value` = 1"
```

When I chain the queries, I want to get the intersection of results from the two scopes.  I want the sql to have the same meaning as this:

```
SELECT `foos`.* from `foos` 
INNER JOIN `bars` AS `bars1` ON `bars1`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `bars` AS `bars2` ON `bars2`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id`
WHERE `bars1`.`method_value` = 1 AND `bars2`.`method_value` = 0
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I think the problem is as you suggest, that when scopes are chained, where and join clauses are not merged, but instead replaced (I think this is getting changed in Rails 4).  Would it be so terrible just to make a third scope?

Comment: Tom, there are a bunch of simple, one-time-use solutions for this problem.  The version with aliases on the join tables is clunky but works the way I want it to.  At this point, I am looking for the more general 'rails way' solution for a query that requires two joins onto the same table.  I just added a full example with working code to the question.  Please take a look and let me know if it clarifies my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it doesn't work?  What does the SQL say is happening?  I just mocked up a model...

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  scope :one, lambda { joins(:bars).where('x = 1') }
  scope :two, lambda { joins(:bars).where('x = 2') }
end
```

And ran it in console... and the query looks fine... granted, it won't return any results as the conditions are impossible to satisfy, but everything was merged/chained as I'd expect.

```
Foo.one.two.to_sql
 => "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` 
     INNER JOIN `bars` ON `bars`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id` 
     WHERE (x = 1) AND (x = 2)"
```

This is with Rails 3.2.8...

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I will try testing on rails 3.2 tomorrow and see if I get a better result.  
My problem with your example is that the sql it returns is not what I am expecting.  It is returning all foos with a bar that has x=1 and x=2.  I am looking for all foos with a bar with x=1 and another bar with x=2.  In my opinion, Foo.one.two should return the intersection of Foo.one and Foo.two.  In this example it does not.  Is there a different way to code this to get what I am looking for?

Comment: Chaining scopes is an AND'd sql condition, not an intersection.  You want `Foo.one + Foo.two`

Comment: The result of two conditions ANDed together should be an intersection of their results.  If Foo.one returns `[a, b, c]` and Foo.two returns `[b, c, d]`, the Foo.one.two should be the intersection, `[b, c]`.  This is normally true but is surprisingly not true in the example you gave.  I have edited my original question with a concrete example.  Please take a look and see if it clarifies my problem.

Comment: No, not necessarily.  If those two conditions create an impossible condition.. say x = 1 AND x = 2 then you won't get any rows back. You're original query required that "method" equal both "late?" and "complete?".  That will result in no rows being returned because it's impossible for a row to satisfy both conditions.  If you really only want a single SQL query you need to rewrite it to use something like "method IN ('late?', 'complete?')" or hijack AR and use SQL's UNION.  It might be UNION is available somewhere in Arel, I don't know...

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem.  I want a query that returns all Foos with one bar with x=1 and another bar with x=2.  I am trying to figure out the 'rails way' to do this.  Here is handwritten query that returns the results I want: `SELECT 'foos'.* from 'foos' INNER JOIN 'bars' AS 'bars1' ON 'bars1'.'foo_id' = 'foos'.'id' INNER JOIN 'bars' AS 'bars2' ON 'bars2'.'foo_id' = 'foos'.'id' WHERE 'bars1'.'x' = 1 AND 'bars2'.'x' = 2`

Comment: Ah!  No, you're right, I didn't understand.  That I've no experience with in Rails :/

Comment: @jeremiahishere Could you please share as to how you solved this problem?

Comment: This one is a bit of a mess.  You can see the solution I picked around line 42-49 of this file: https://github.com/jeremiahishere/denormalizer/blob/master/lib/denormalizer/denormalize.rb

The gist of the solution is a randomized table alias that is used for the scope:


    `scope_index = <call a method>;
    table_alias = "dnmos_#{table_name}_#{scope_index}";
    scope :my_scope, lambda { joins("INNER JOIN #{table_name} AS #{table_alias} on #{table_alias}.id='#{other_table}.id'").where(...)}`;

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to get `saved_lates` and on those ones, you want to get `saved_completes`

Instead of this(this one does not work i think in below the explanation very clear): `Task.saved_lates.saved_completes`
What you can do basically:

```
tasks_saved_lates = Task.saved_lates
tasks_saved_completes = Task.saved_completes
tasks_saved_lates.merge(tasks_saved_completes) # this basically get intersection between the results
```

You can look at `merge` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge).